# Apple II: ProDOS partitions on floppy disks?

Tags: apple-ii, floppy-disk, apple-dos

On the Apple II using ProDOS, was it possible to create partitions on a floppy disk? Would it be possible to have two or more partitions on a 140k 5.25" or 800k 3.5" disk?

(The question here is not practicality, but just if it could be done at all.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ProDOS supports up to 2 storage device volumes per slot, but does not support partitioning within those volumes. It is a function of the firmware provided with the storage device controller (i.e. SCSI Card) to map partitions on a storage device to volumes for ProDOS.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create partitions with arbitrary contents, but programs like Glen Bredon's [DOS MASTER](http://www.apple2.org.za/gswv/a2zine/System/DosMaster_docs.txt) allow you to have multiple DOS 3.3 volumes on a ProDOS volume, including 3.5" disks and hard drives.  I believe something similar was possible for Apple Pascal volumes.