# How does ProDOS allow for multiple volumes to exist on a single device?

Tags: apple-ii, storage

On the back of [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/apple-ii-prodos-partitions-on-floppy-disks), it got me thinking that it has always been that ProDOS would only support a ",D1" and ",D2" on a slot, i.e. slot 6 would have two addressible drives. With my 20MB Sider hard disk back in the day, I had only two partitions there as well which mapped `/HARD1` to `,S7,D1` and `/HARD2` to `,S7,D2`.

Ever since I've been playing with emulators that supported hard disks, I did notice that you can have multiple volumes mounted on slot 7. Though ProDOS doesn't seem to allow you to do (say) `,S7,D6`, you are able to mount a `/HARD6` (to keep with my naming scheme from before).

How did ProDOS allow this behavior? And in the spirit of the question I linked to at the start of this, why wouldn't you be able to mount more than one volume on a floppy controller? The thing which makes it a touch puzzling is that SmartPort devices apparently could map themselves to other slots as needed and also devices such as a CFFA 3000 allow for mapping volumes to multiple slots and exceeding `,D3` conventions.

Comment: ProDOS allows volumes with multiple partitions, my IIgs has a hard disk with ProDOS and HFS partitions to divide up the 256 mb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Update**
>   As of the release of *ProDOS 2.5 alpha#5*, up to **37 drives are supported**. This is done by increasing the number of mapped drives per slot from 2 to 8, which would theoretically allow 56 drives. However, there is only enough reserved memory for the table of unit numbers to hold up to 37 entries.

ProDOS, being an 8-bit OS designed to run in 64K, uses very small and efficient internal data structures to map logical entities, like your volume */HARD6* to physical hardware entities. Specifically, ProDOS maps its block devices (all disk drives) to unit numbers that are 1-byte long with the high 4-bits specified as **DSSS**, where D is the drive and SSS is the slot. Since D is only one bit, only 2 drives are supported. Since SSS excludes the value 0, 7 slots are supported (just like the hardware has slots 1 through 7). So, there is a limit of 14 unique unit numbers, and that means a limit of 14 physical drives (or partitions, since partitions are handled by the HD controller).

*SmartPort* controllers support more than 2 drives for a single slot, and can theoretically support up to 127 devices. During initialization, when ProDOS encounters a *SmartPort* controller with more than two drives, it uses *mirroring* to map the additional drives to unit numbers associated with different slots. So, four SmartPort drives connected via slot 5 will be mapped by ProDOS: S5,D1 S5,D2 S2,D1 S2,D2. Each of those 4 drives will also have a logical volume based on the name of the disk. So, that is how you end up with a */HARD3* and */HARD4* that are assigned to slot 2, even though the actual card in slot 2 is probably a serial card.

Much more detail about this is available in **ProDOS 8 Technical Note #20**.

Comment: Link to the technical note: http://www.1000bit.it/support/manuali/apple/technotes/pdos/tn.pdos.20.html

Comment: If you want a 6502-based system with more than 37 drives you'll have to get a Commodore system which allows device numbers from 8 to 31 and two unit numbers per device for a total of 48 drives.